# Error en funcion javascript ejecutada desde codebehind + asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Al apretar el boton 'BUSCAR' estoy llamando una funcion de javascript desde el codebehind con la siguiente linea:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "deudaAct", "obtener_comprobantes_actualizados()", True)
```

La misma anda bien. El problema es que quiero utilizar esta misma funcion en el load del aspx.vb cuando envio un parametro por la url y me da el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: obtener_comprobantes_actualizados is not defined
at automotor.aspx?id=18886:798
```

Aclaro que la funcion se encuentra en un archivo llamado myjs.js, pero al parecer la busca en  automotor.aspx?id=18886

Answer (score 0):

La solución es la siguiente:

- Debes terminar tu declaración de Javascript con un punto y coma.

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me,GetType(Page),"deudaAct","obtener_comprobantes_actualizados();", True)`